# What are document to vector methods (doc2vec), that rely on a tensorflow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, doc2vec

I am currently trying to implement a neural network that uses a doc2vec vector, and then uses that to work further. 
I have a machine which only allows me to use tensorflow (this is a requirement!), so I need a model to transform a sentence / paragraph to a vector.

I know about gensim's `doc2vec` and [this](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/TensorFlow-Machine-Learning-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter%2007/doc2vec.py) implementation. I have experience with gensim's implementation, but it apparently does not use tensorflow in the backend. The latter link, however, does not work without a few hours / days of debugging it seems.

I would be helpful for any links and recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

While exploring I ran into this guy's tests.

https://github.com/sachinruk/doc2vec_tf/blob/master/test_doc2vec.ipynb

Hope it can be useful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19941595)

Comment: I agree, but this question only asks for links and references